# lisp code not indenting after paredit slurping, etc

Tags: smartparens, paredit

When I use `smartparens-mode` or `paredit-mode` to shift parens around (e.g. `paredit-forward-slurp-sexp`) the effected forms are not being indented appropriately. For example if I add a `let` and then slurp the next sexp the paren is placed appropriately but the inner form is not auto-indented.

This used to work for me but for some reason it is not now. What are some possible config problems that would prevent the auto-indentation from happening? BTW, I'm using a slightly modified version of prelude.

Comment: I just took a look at the code for the Smartparens slurp function (`sp-forward-slurp-sexp`), and all of the indentation work appears to be encapsulated in a single call to `indent-region`.  Does `indent-region` work properly when you call it directly?  (By default, it's bound to `C-M-\`.)

Comment: @AaronHarris thanks for the idea. I checked and `indent-region` doesn't work either. That gives me a place to look further, thanks!